# WCF message interceptor or operation invoker

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

What is the recommended approach for tracing and logging incoming/outcoming messages into a WCF service?

I've seen this done with an operation invoker, but am wondering are there any benefits in using a message interceptor instead?

Comment: Googling for `wcf tracing` brings quite a few results. From what I remember, you could just configure tracing in a web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to log/trace the messages, I think the **MessageInspector** makes more sense.

If we compare **IOperationBehavior** ([IOperationBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.ioperationbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) ) and **IClientMessageInspector** ([IClientMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) ) for instance, we can notice that IClientMessageInspector alread has the message object in some methods, like **AfterReceiveReply** and **BeforeSendRequest**, that are good places to intercept the messages.

Besides, operation invokers are only applied on server side, so if you need a complete trace of your messages, both client and server, the best approach is using MessageInspector.

The Carlos Figueira's blog has more details about using message inspectors and invokers: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility/

Hope it helps